# Lookup key pair value based of previously found key in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, python-requests

I hope that title makes sense.

I'm trying to filter through a list generated from an API call to get the selected matching record and place that in a dynamic label.

Currently, I am able to use the `requests` module to make an API call to a Airtable sheet I have with customers' name and other required fields. I make the request, parse the results into JSON and then use a for loop to iterate through the results to just produce a list of names, shown below:

```
def get_airtable_records():
    response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    parse = json.loads(response.text)
    result = []

    for i in parse['records']:
        result.append(f"{i['fields']['Name']}")
    return result
```

An example of a returned record from the Airtable API is below:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "rec1bg______",
      "createdTime": "1960-01-01T01:18:50.000Z",
      "fields": {
        "Status": "queued",
        "Name": "SOME NAME"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When `result` gets returned, it places each customers' name into a Tkinter ComboBox with:

```
values = get_airtable_records()

# Some other code

combo = ttk.ComboBox(frame, values=values, font=("Arial", 20)
combo.set ("Please choose one")

# Some other code
```

That works brilliantly, but now I would like to get the corresponding "Status" for the selected customer into a Tkinter Label using StringVar.

Now I have a selected customer in the aforementioned Tkinter ComboBox, I would like to have their current status places in a dynamic label next to the drop down and when I chance the selection from one customer to another, it changes the status label accordingly.

My current attempt - albeit a terrible one - works like this:

```
status = []

def get_status(i):
    for i in parse['records']:
        key = frozenset(i.items())
        if key in parse:
            status.append(i)
    return status
```

This function runs in between the `get_airtable_records()` function shown above.

I'm no programmer so I assume that is wrong so would appreciate some guidance!

Comment: For one thing, `status = []` should be *inside* the function.

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. You should design the application logic and implement the preliminary version by yourself. What do you mean by "I'm no programmer"? You are learning Python and the ```tkinter```. You are a programmer.

Comment: Anyway, create a dictionary with ```i['fields']['Name']``` as a key and ```i['fields']['Status']``` as a value.